# TextArea formatting in Flutter

Tags: android, forms, flutter

How to include the below bar

[image]

to flutter **Textarea** so that I should be able to format input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Flutter Html Editor - Enhanced: https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced